# What does deploy_env do in Capistrano deploy script?

Tags: capistrano

In the [Capistrano Multi-staging documentation](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) `set :deploy_env, 'production'` is used. Is `deploy_env` the same as `rails_env` which [tells Capistrano which environment to use when running the app/migrations](http://groups.google.com/group/capistrano/browse_thread/thread/4de622f8d569a617)?

If they are not the same, what does `deploy_env` do and how should it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a typo. See [Issue #189](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/189) for capistrano gem on github. Use `rails_env` not `deploy_env`.